# KITKAT error : Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-multidex

I am getting error of class not found on kitkat and jellybean. I've test my app in jellybean, kitkat Emulators and lollipo and marshmellow physical devices.

I searched many post but all are showing that uninstall and clear, or use `play-service-maps` instead of `play-service`. But i need to use `play-services` because of markers and all the things. 
**Please help me out of this.**

**Error**

```
12-12 21:08:59.289 3396-3396/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.thetech.ambulancerequest, PID: 3396
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thetech.ambulancerequest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.thetech.ambulancerequest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.thetech.ambulancerequest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.thetech.ambulancerequest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my **app>gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thetech.ambulancerequest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Ambulance Requests-$versionName")
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**SplashSvcreen**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        MultiDex.install(this);
```

Comment: You don't need the whole `play-services` library to use maps. Using `play-service-maps` is enough

Comment: I tried that one but i used `gms.location.places` and `LocationServices` and after replacing play-services to play-service-maps it shows errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this on your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```

for this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
```

Note that [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) recommends depnding only on the neccesary Play Services modles instead of depending on the whole Play Services library:

> If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them. For information on how to do this, see Selectively compiling APIs into your executable.

Comment: So, tell me, Why i dont use `play-services` this is recommended by google docs. I learn these tutorials from official site. I want to know why this is not working with `play-services` ?